# Need help to get data out of an as400 system

Tags: ibm-midrange

I have a plenty of tables and databases. most of the tables have empty spaces and no table col has a descriptive name.. can somebody help me to get the data out of there? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [this link](http://search400.techtarget.com/tip/Know-all-fields-and-tables-on-your-iSeries)

For documentation purposes here is the key information.

> If you need to search one field or one file, follow this code on SQL:
>
> `Select * from Syscolumns`
>
> or
>
> `Select * from Systables`

I believe the specific library for this is `QSYS2`.

**Update to add directions with F.R.O.G.**:

1. Connect to your server.
2. On the DB2 tab, choose File | New.
3. In the middle pane, enter in your SQL statement. `Select * from QSYS2.Syscolumns where table_schema = 'LIBRARY'`
4. Press Enter
5. The Statement will run. Narrow your results as needed.
6. Once you get the results you want, you can right click on the bottom pane and see your options from there.

Comment: i went to that link, and i had to register.. it asked a lot of things and only shows other generic links...

Comment: That is why I pulled the key information out of the article. I didn't remember if you had to register or not. Really what I posted was most of the tip. Take a look at the two tables. This should get you what you want.

Comment: I opened my server with the frog and have: 192.168.1.3 -> libraries -> QSYS2 then here I see authorizations... tables and other variables. When I click on tables, i have "table" and then i just have the cols name. How to see the entries (data)?

Comment: just ran my query but i didn't get what i expected... I want to use a specific database/library, how do I do?

Comment: I have a library that it doesnt appear to exists in the frog app. If i open the "transfer data from iseries server", I add my library, i can browse it. So my question now is: how do i add my library to frog in order to be able to browse it. thanks

Comment: I have used it very little. Sorry, I can't help you much more than that.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Client Access (or iSeries Access) you have a tool called "Transfer Data from iSeries Server". This will allow you to easily dump all of the data into a CSV or file type of your choice.

Another option is to use `CPYTOIMPF`. There is a ton of documentation on that tool online.

A third option is [F.R.O.G. for IBM i5](http://www.innovativesys.net/?page_id=4). This is a free tool that allows you to run SQL statements. You can then export the data to a CSV.

Comment: i've opened the Transfer Data from iSeries Server and then how do i extract just the names of the tables? thanks

Comment: Oh, I though you wanted the data. I have a better way then. I'll create a new answer. Sorry of the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do exactly this a long time ago and ended up using a very crude solution - I used a terminal emulator which had screen recording functionality and then dumped the AS400 data to the terminal. I then wrote a simple program which took the captured terminal session and filtered the text fields into a database. It was ugly, but it was just for a one-off data export to a new system and most importantly it worked.

Comment: really? :o may i know more details of the process?

Comment: There is not much more to tell - find an AS400 terminal emulator that has screen capture/recording, have someone who knows the AS400 dump each database table to the screen, capture the data for each table, write a filter in Perl or whatever to process each file into a suitable form for importing into a database.

Comment: There are much more elegant and easier to do methods of dumping data than this.

Comment: @Mike: I'm sure there are much more elegant ways, but sometimes a quick and dirty solution like this is all you need if it's a "one off".

Answer (score 0):

This statement will pull all fields and field names from all files in a library.

```
Select system_column_name, column_name, system_table_name, table_name, column_text, column_heading from QSYS2.Syscolumns where table_schema = 'LIBRARY';
```