# Im using access 2003 to view some as400 tables and databases. I would need a way to export all the names of the databases

Tags: excel, ms-access, ibm-midrange

Im using access 2003 to view some as400 tables and databases. I would need a way to export all the names of the databases to excel. (And if possible mark the ones that have no contents)

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Otherwise you can try Symtrax "Starquery for Excel" which is a software that allows to export automatically AS400 tables to Excel files and generate reporting tables.

This software's purpose is to give access to AS400 tables for end-users without any computer skills.

Just try it for free for 10 days

http://www.symtrax.com/Pages/en-us/StarQuery-Suite-Business-Intelligence-Make-Informed-Decisions-By-Using-Up-to-Date-Real-Time-Company-Data.aspx

Or ask me questions if you have some :)

Answer (score 0):

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5310260/need-help-to-get-data-out-of-an-as400-system/5313086#5313086) on your other question. If you are wanting everything dumped out, I gave you a couple of tools that allow this to be easily.